# I am using https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project . How to add more scripts after "create-project"?

Tags: 8, composer

I want to use https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project to generate several customized projects.

If I want a contrib module to be available for all instances, what is the best way to get them when running "composer create-project"?

I thought to add this logic (to add contrib modules by default) in scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php but this file doesn't seem to be suitable for customizations.

Is there an easy way to add other scripts to run on project creation?
Or which other way should I chose?

Comment: Take a look in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkD5jUHL190) Erich Beyrent talk about 'Configuration As Dependency: Managing Drupal 8 Configuration with git and Composer', for sure that you will find your answer and beyond.

Comment: @Vagner in which part do they talk about using https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project ? Seems like plain composer/drupal, so it doesn't help me here.

Comment: Ok @Vagner maybe you are suggesting me to use a two repos and different branches for each project?! That seems a very odd solution. The video has now 35 views, it doesn't seem "the" solution. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I dont know your needs, and as pointed on [video](https://youtu.be/vkD5jUHL190?t=939), "There is no 'recomended' workflow" (-Mathew Tift) after all, every project is unique. Use this video just as use case. In that, he uses one main repo for code base, and another for configuration (see [here how and why](https://youtu.be/vkD5jUHL190?t=1080) he takes this approach), if this dont fit for your needs, you have the flexibility to change where to you makes sense. Drupal 8 é interessante por isso, permite várias configurações, escolha a que venha ser melhor para ti. ;)

Answer (score 0):

when you use `create-project` you're creating a new composer project with a  **composer.json** based on the package type.

The **composer.json** file is highly customizable. You can set install paths for specific modules/libraries and/or set a list of default modules to install when the project is created. You can also apply patches and run post-install scripts if nessecary. Plenty more options as well. I suggest jumping into the [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/).

to add a module to **composer.json** run:

```
composer require drupal/module_name 8.1.*@dev
```

Once you have a composer.json the way you like, you can take that composer.json file, place in a different empty project directory and you can simply run `composer-install` and it will install the drupal project, all the modules in the appropriate directories specified inside the **composer.json** file, post install commands ect, it will also write a **composer.lock** file if one doesn't exist. No need to create a brand new project everytime, just manage custom **composer.json** files thats the beautfy of composer.

https://www.lullabot.com/articles/goodbye-drush-make-hello-composer

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

https://getcomposer.org/doc/

Comment: But that composer.json will be used to install modules that are unique for each project, so sharing them across all instances doesn't seem practical. I think the best place to have this settings is in the upper level, in "drupal-composer/drupal-project" ... but then to change the composer.json there is also tricky, because it will be updated over time when I do a git pull to get updates.

Comment: If you share the same composer.json across all instances of course you will get the same results...  If you had different composer.json files you would have different results. 

 If you do it at the `drupal-composer/drupal-project` level you still have to make sure versions are correct or the module wont be added to the project.... 

This is what composer is for, it wont allow you to add or update stuff if it will break based on incompatible versions. Managing versions is part of the game now, if you want to blindly update stuff composer wont allow you to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this.

drupal-project is a composer project like any other. Create your own repository, e.g. by forking on github. Then add all your standard modules there and use your own repository with create-project.

You can also create a repository with a composer.json that contains nothing but dependencies. https://github.com/webflo/drupal-core-strict is something like that, except that it enforces specific versions of core dependencies. Simply add the modules you want to use there, then add that with composer require on a new project and it will merge it together and download all those projects.